# Возврат функцией текст по его ид

Tags: postgresql

Только разбираюсь с функциями в PostgreSQL, прошу помощи, никак не соображу, как синтаксически правильно написать. Функция простейшая, должна по ид вернуть текст, но pgAdmin ругается, syntax error. Код

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.foo(id integer)
RETURNS text
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
VOLATILE
COST 100
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
txt TEXT;
BEGIN
txt := select tst.txt from tst where tst.id = $1;
RETURN txt ;
END; 
$BODY$;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наиболее распространён для этих целей синтаксис [`select .. into`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.foo(id integer)
RETURNS text
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
VOLATILE
COST 100
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
txt TEXT;
BEGIN
select tst.txt into txt from tst where tst.id = $1;
RETURN txt ;
END; 
$BODY$;
```

Этот синтаксис позволяет присваивать значения сразу списку переменных:

```
select field1, field2 into var1, var2 from ...
```

Для одной переменной вполне можно использовать и оператор присваивания, единственно что необходимо поправить в вашей функции - сам запрос должен быть в скобках:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.foo(id integer)
RETURNS text
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
VOLATILE
COST 100
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
txt TEXT;
BEGIN
txt := (select tst.txt from tst where tst.id = $1);
RETURN txt ;
END; 
$BODY$;
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!!